# Android studio 2.0 Beta-6 error compileOptions.incremental=false

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I updated to the latest Android Studio 2.0 beta-6.

Error:The android.incrementalJavaCompile property has been replaced by a DSL property. Please add the following to your build.gradle instead:

```
android {
  compileOptions.incremental = false
}
```

My current gradle file contains

```
android{
..

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        incremental = false;
}
...

}
```

Still does not compile.

I am using 3rd party libraries like Dagger 2, retrofit2, Rxjava, AndroidAnnotations etc. I commented out all the dependencies but still does not compile.

Some other details:

```
    androidBuildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
    androidMinSdkVersion = 16
    androidTargetSdkVersion = 23
    androidCompileSdkVersion = 23
```

Answer (score 4):

Figured out after wasting a few hours.

Part 1:
Go to Android Studio (or File on Windows) -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> remove

```
-Pandroid.incrementalJavaCompile = false
```

if present from Command-line Options.

Part 2:
Add to your build.gradle of all your android modules (application or library)

```
android {
    compileOptions.incremental = false
}
```